# Extend a Singleton with PHP 5.2.X

Tags: php, singleton

I have this code running on PHP 5.2.6

```
class Singleton {
    static private $instance = false;
    private $id = false;
    protected function __construct() {
        $this->id = uniqid();
    }

    static public function instance() {
        if (!self :: $instance) {
            self :: $instance = new self();
        }
        return self :: $instance;
    }
    public function get_id() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

class Chucknorris extends Singleton {

}

echo "php version = ".phpversion()."<br>";

$singleton = Singleton::instance();
echo get_class($singleton)."<br>";
echo "singleton id = ".$singleton->get_id()."<br>";

$chucknorris = Chucknorris::instance();
echo get_class($chucknorris)."<br>";
echo "chucknorris id = ".$chucknorris->get_id()."<br>";
```

Here's the output

```
php version = 5.2.6
Singleton
singleton id = 4ea7dca7d8f23
Singleton
chucknorris id = 4ea7dca7d8f23
```

When I ask for an instance of Chucknorris, I always get the Singleton one. I'd like to find out a way to extend the Singleton.

I know we can use get_called_class method to do it but it comes only with PHP 5.3. Is there anyway I can extend a Singleton without redefining the design pattern in the extended classes ?

Comment: if you can upgrade your PHP version to 5.3, than you can use static:: instead of self:: Than,  you can declare your static instance on the child class, but static:: will call the child variable, while self:: will call the one in the current defined class.

Comment: Maybe this is an interesting article? http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/135-Extending-Singletons.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simulate the get_class_function if it doesn't exist with 5.3 PHP version ?
This code may answer your question.

```
if (!function_exists('get_called_class')) {
    function get_called_class() {
        $bt = debug_backtrace();
        $lines = file($bt[1]['file']);
        preg_match(
            '/([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)::'.$bt[1]['function'].'/',
            $lines[$bt[1]['line']-1],
            $matches
        );
        return $matches[1];
    }
}

abstract class Singleton {
    private $id = false;

    protected function __construct() {
        $this->id = uniqid();
    }

    static public function instance() {
        static $instances = array();
        $called_class_name = get_called_class();
        if (!isset($instances[$called_class_name])) {
            $instances[$called_class_name] = new $called_class_name();
        }
        return $instances[$called_class_name];
    }

    public function get_id() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

class Chucknorris extends Singleton {}
class Brucelee extends Singleton {}

echo "php version = ".phpversion()."<br>";

$chucknorris = Chucknorris::instance();
echo get_class($chucknorris)."<br>";
echo "chucknorris id = ".$chucknorris->get_id()."<br>";

$brucelee = Brucelee::instance();
echo get_class($brucelee)."<br>";
echo "brucelee id = ".$brucelee->get_id()."<br>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet in PHP < 5.3 is to use a Singleton Factory:

```
class Singleton
{
    private $id = false;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->id = uniqid();
    }

    public function get_id() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

class SingletonFactory
{
    private static $instance_array = array();

    public static function getInstance($class_name)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance_array[$class_name]))
        {
            self::$instance_array[$class_name] = new $class_name();
        }
        return self::$instance_array[$class_name];
    }
}

class Chucknorris extends Singleton {}


$singleton = SingletonFactory::getInstance('Singleton');
echo get_class($singleton)."<br>";
echo "singleton id = ".$singleton->get_id()."<br>";

$chucknorris = SingletonFactory::getInstance('Chucknorris');
echo get_class($chucknorris)."<br>";
echo "chucknorris id = ".$chucknorris->get_id()."<br>";
```

The only downside here is that your Singleton constructor is public.. so that's a basic violation of that pattern.

Update:
Here's a version that removes the public constructor (warning: this is getting into messy/hacky/poor design territory)

```
class Singleton
{
    private $id = false;

    public function __construct() {
        $back = debug_backtrace(false);
        if (!isset($back[1]['class']) || $back[1]['class'] != 'SingletonFactory')
        {
            throw new Exception('Consturctor not available, use SingletonFactory::getInstance("CLASSNAME")');
        }

        $this->id = uniqid();
    }

    public function get_id() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

class SingletonFactory
{
    private static $instance_array = array();

    public static function getInstance($class_name)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance_array[$class_name]))
        {
            self::$instance_array[$class_name] = new $class_name($class_name);
        }
        return self::$instance_array[$class_name];
    }
}

class Chucknorris extends Singleton {}


$singleton = SingletonFactory::getInstance('Singleton');
echo get_class($singleton)."<br>";
echo "singleton id = ".$singleton->get_id()."<br>";

$chucknorris = SingletonFactory::getInstance('Chucknorris');
echo get_class($chucknorris)."<br>";
echo "chucknorris id = ".$chucknorris->get_id()."<br>";

$badchuck = new Chucknorris(); // Exception!
```

Comment: you are on the right track. However the Singleton doesn't have to have a public constructor. It could be done with a static function called `getNewInstance` which fires the constructor each time it is called.

Comment: Yep! It's not great -- I did mention the lack of a public constructor in the original answer though. Note, getNewInstance() would have to be defined in each subclass of Singleton -- which would defy the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine just the `getinstance` method (and the instance itself) in `Chucknorris` to get an instance of it instead of the parent, but I'm not exactly sure what your end goal is. Just change the extending class to:

```
class Chucknorris extends Singleton {
    static private $instance = false;

    static public function instance()
    {
        if (!self :: $instance) {
            self :: $instance = new self();
        }
        return self :: $instance;
    }
}
```

Is this what you want? And if so - what is the reason you want it? I could think of a few, but would be glad if you share you goal.

Comment: i think the ideea of extending is not to write again the same code.

Comment: Only the getinstance method is the same - everything else can be extended.

Comment: @DanBizdadea: If the OP is looking for late static binding, then PHP 5.2.x is the wrong PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will most likely work if you move `static private $instance = false;` to the subclass and make it `protected` instead of `private`.
You also need to replace `self::` with `static::` so the static var is set in the subclass. 
This requires PHP 5.3 - however, this shouldn't be a problem because PHP 5.2 reached end-of-life/support (that includes security updates!) as of january 2011!

Comment: And don't forget to copy the `instance()` function.

Comment: I moved this line to the subclass, I got _Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Singleton::$instance_ It's normal as Singleton object tried to modify this property. Same thing when I copied it in the subclass.

Comment: Make it protected instead of private.